How to correct say: "Gaius de deo" or "Gaius de dei" or "Gaius de deus"?
I wanna say "Gaius from god" in Latin. That means God create Gaius or God send Gaius out.
How to correct say: "Gaius de deo" or "Gaius de dei" or "Gaius de deus" ?

The praeposition de always takes the ablative case, which is deo.
Note that de can mean "down from, away from", but also "about, concerning". Other options: e/ex "out of", a/ab/abs "from, away from, by".
You could also add a participle to make it clear:

Gaius deo natus ("Gaius born of god / son of god": this usually goes with a bare ablative without a praeposition)


Gaius ex deo ortus ("Gaius who came to be out of god")


Gaius a deo factus ("Gaius who was created by god")


Gaius de caelo missus ("Gaius sent from heaven")

